# Does nginx proxy handle well on SEESSION ID?

Tags: apache, session, nginx

For example,
I have a nginx server as a front-end and two apache servers with mod_php.
As you know, php has sesssion support, which set a cookie identifying the SESSION ID but the real data is stored at the server.
When a user is set with this kind of cookie by one apache server, will his other HTTP requests be fowarded to the same apache server before the session/cookie expires ?

Comment: This question is off-topic on this site. It is not a programming question, it is a system administration question. You should ask that at http://www.serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, no, the requests will not necessarily be forwarded to the same server, so your application using sessions will be broken.

Go to your favorite search engine and type "nginx affinity" and "nginx sticky" for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will do that if you follow the documentation for multiple back-end servers usage:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule

But better consider storing sessions in a some sort of shared storage, e.g. Memcached or a database.